# How to keep pulseaudiorunning for ever?

Tags: audio, debian, pulse-audio

I have tried a lot of things to get pulseaudio running after Mozilla stopped Alsa support. Every time the pulseaudio process stops claiming it has nothing to do which is true.

I'm here
start-pulseaudio-x11
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: --start not supported for system instances.

Comment: I did a lot of searching but this is where I am, `/usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: --start not supported for system instances.` I'm not able to figure this out. Searching the internet to no avail.

Comment: You are right it is deviating, I am a beginner stacker and should have started earlier. I have a hardtime capatilizing for example, however this what is your question about screen sending me from Stack Overflow to Super User is great for me. I am aware I may not deviate. Please remove this whole topic for me.